# What should you keep in mind when doing operations on doubly-linked lists?

Tags: c++, data-structures

For example, my instructor said something about not having any memory freed, and deleting pointers when doing operations with linked lists. Furthermore, he said that while doing operations on a doubly-linked lists, you should make sure that your edge cases are okay. Can anyone expand on this? I'm not sure I get what he fully means.

For example, this is the sort of linked list we are working on:

```
 struct Node {
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        T datum;
    };

Node *first;   // points to first Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
Node *last;    // points to last Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
```

Comment: Write an implementation of it and everything'll become clear.

Comment: Ask your professor, that's what he's there for.

Comment: Edge case: => extreme case. 1) Empty list. 2) List with 1 element. 3) The head of a list 4) The tail of the list. 5) The normal situation (an element in the middle of a list).

Comment: You should keep in mind that you are doing operations on a double-linked list

Comment: When you're dealing with dynamic memory, the most important thing you should keep in mind is to not screw it up.

Comment: On a side note, you **delete** a **memory block**. Typically that's done with a pointer to that memory block, and the syntax is `delete ptr`, but what you're deleting a not a pointer, but the memory that it points to.

Comment: Off topic: use `nullptr`, not `0` to mark empty links. `0` is sooooo 1970.

Comment: When performing operations on a doubly linked list, keep in mind that one use random access (like an array).  One has to follow links to look for items in the container.

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with pointers, you always want to make sure you `delete` any `new` objects that are no longer in use.  That's so there aren't any memory leaks.

Edge conditions are, for example, when inserting an element, does it work for an empty list, when the item will be inserted as the first element, as the last element?  Normally, when implementing insert we do the logic for a typical element (i.e. one in the middle of an existing list).  But it should work for all cases.  The cases I mentioned could be considered edge conditions and have to be considered for each an every operation you want to implement for the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a ´struct´, instead of a ´class´, implement some functions for operations for each node.

UPDATE:
I mention `class` because, the functions I comment, are usually implemented as object' methods, in the object-oriented version of a linked-list,
yet these operations apply as well in procedural programming.

Example:

```
struct Node {
        Node *next;
        Node *prev;
        T datum;
    };

Node *first;   // points to first Node in list, or 0 if list is empty
Node *last;    // points to last Node in list, or 0 if list is empty

void NodesLink(Node* A, Node* B)
{
  if ((A != NULL) && (B != NULL))
  {
     A->next = B;
     B->prev = A;
  }
} // void NodesLink (...)

void NodesInsertAfter(Node* A, Node* NewNode)
{
  if ((A != NULL) && (NewNode != NULL))
  {
     Node* B = A->next;
     NodesLink(A, NewNode);
     NodesLink(NewNode, B);
  }
} // void NodesLink (...)
```

That independent utility functions will make your code more consistent, and easy to debug and fix.

Comment: In C++, the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is default access. So I don't get the point of "Since you're using a `struct`, instead of a `class`".

Answer (score 0):

Some of the edge cases might be
 (a) No node
(b) Only one node
(c) Adding node at head/tail
(d) Avoiding infinite loop while traversing list
(e) Avoiding memory leaks and dangling pointers

These are the basic checks that ought to be made.